# How come Blender does not reconize a mesh from my makehuman program?

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting, makehuman

my mhx2 function does not work so I have been converting my makehuman
models with an autodesk converter to FBX or importing them in DAE,
but when I try to bind the rig to the mesh, I get an error message that says no mesh found.I have tryed both rigged and un-rigged models and no luck even though I can see the mesh when I am rigging, my ctrl-p to use auto weights seems to have no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

First: It would be helpful to know exactly which version of makehuman and exactly which version of blender you are using. The advice on how to proceed will be different depending on these answers.

At least DAE should work out of the box for exporting a makehuman character to blender, although material transparency might need to be tweaked after import.

This said, the recommended approach for exporting a character from makehuman to blender is still MHX2 rather than FBX or DAE. MHX2 has been ported to blender 2.80, but the import button is now available on the T-shelf rather than in the import menu.

I would thus recommend trying to get MHX2 up and running rather than try working through FBX or DAE, when the end target is blender.

As an alternative, and if you are using makehuman 1.2.0 alpha 2 or later, you can use the new blender integration to import a fully rigged character. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAwfR-G813g for a general introduction and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEaVZVbTJOQ for notes specific to blender 2.80.

Comment: my make human is 1.1.1 and my Blender is 2.79b though I have 2.80,on a new win 10 ,  just starting to fool with it.but thanks will try all of this out had almost gave up and been using some thing else called  " build a body" as a rook the learning curve has been very steep but am working on it.